# static block is doubling when update Layout Update XML

Tags: magento-1.8, template, cms, static-block, layout-update

I am trying to update the layout of the right sidebar on a CMS page, and the block is doubling, I have created a Static Block and then called using the following method:

```
<reference name="right">
<block type="cms/block" name="right.permanent.callout">
<action method="setBlockId"><block_id>about-right</block_id></action>
</block>
</reference>
```

After creating this, the Static Block doubled the content on the page, as you can see in this [link](http://www.avenueart.co.uk/contact-us/)

Does anyone know what might be causing this?

This is the code related to the sidebar in my local.xml:

```
    <remove name="catalog.compare.sidebar"/>
    <remove name="left.reports.product.viewed" />-->
    <remove name="right.reports.product.viewed" />
    <remove name="right.reports.product.compared"/>
    <remove name="wishlist_sidebar"/>
    <remove name="tags_popular"/>
    <remove name="right.poll"/>
    <remove name="paypal.partner.right.logo"/>
    <remove name="reorder"/>

    <!--<remove name="right.permanent.callout"/>-->
    <remove name="left.permanent.callout"/>
```

Many thanks in advance,

Comment: add `<remove name="right.permanent.callout />` in your local.xml file and tell me what happend in your site?

Comment: Can you please change the name of the block to something else? Then do what @programmer_rkt said.

Comment: By removing {<remove name="right.permanent.callout />} it completely removed the static block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your block name (it is already used by another block). The following works perfectly:

```
<reference name="right">
    <block type="cms/block" name="about.right">
        <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>about-right</block_id></action>
    </block>
</reference>
```